# Using vitest and testing-library is there a way to segregate component renders on a test by test basis?

Tags: testing, vuejs3, vitest, vue-testing-library

I have a simple list component written in Vue3 that I am using to learn how to write automated test with *Vitest* and *testing-library*. However every `test` method seems to be rendered together, causing my `getByText` calls to throw the error **TestingLibraryElementError: Found multiple elements with the text: foo**.

This is the test I have written:

```js
import { describe, it, expect, test } from 'vitest'
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/vue'
import TmpList from '../ui/TmpList.vue'

const listItems = ['foo', 'bar']

describe('TmpList', () => {
    // Test item-content slot rendering
    test('renders item-content slot', () => {
        const slotTemplate = `
        <template v-slot:item-content="{ item }">
            <div> {{ item }} </div>
        </template>`;

        render(TmpList, { props: { listItems }, slots: { 'item-content': slotTemplate } });
        listItems.forEach(li => {
            expect(screen.getByText(li)).toBeTruthy();
        })
    })

    // Test list item interaction
    test('should select item when clicked and is selectable', async () => {
        const slotTemplate = `
        <template v-slot:item-content="{ item }">
            <div> {{ item }} </div>
        </template>`;

        render(TmpList, { props: { listItems, selectable: true }, slots: { 'item-content': slotTemplate } });
        const firstItem = screen.getByText(listItems[0]);
        await fireEvent.click(firstItem);
        expect(firstItem.classList).toContain('selected-item')
    })
})
```

The component:

```html
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(item, index) in listItems" :key="`list-item-${index}`" @click="onItemClick(index)"
            class="rounded mx-2" :class="{
                'selected-item bg-secondary-600/20 text-secondary':
                    selectedIndex == index,
                'hover:bg-zinc-200/30': selectable,
            }">
            <slot name="item-content" :item="item"></slot>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, ref } from "vue";
export interface Props {
    listItems: any[];
    selectable?: boolean;
}
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
    selectable: false,
});

const selectedIndex = ref<number>(-1);

const onItemClick = (index: number) => {
    if (props.selectable) {
        selectedIndex.value = index;
    }
};

</script>
```

This is the full error I get in the terminal:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Found multiple elements with the text: foo

Here are the matching elements:

Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
<div>
  foo
</div>

Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
<div>
  foo
</div>

(If this is intentional, then use the `*AllBy*` variant of the query (like `queryAllByText`, `getAllByText`, or `findAllByText`)).

Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
<body>
  <div>
    <ul
      data-v-96593be0=""
    >

      <li
        class="rounded mx-2"
        data-v-96593be0=""
      >

        <div>
          foo
        </div>

      </li>
      <li
        class="rounded mx-2"
        data-v-96593be0=""
      >

        <div>
          bar
        </div>

      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul
      data-v-96593be0=""
    >

      <li
        class="rounded mx-2 hover:bg-zinc-200/30"
        data-v-96593be0=""
      >

        <div>
          foo
        </div>

      </li>
      <li
        class="rounded mx-2 hover:bg-zinc-200/30"
        data-v-96593be0=""
      >

        <div>
          bar
        </div>

      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
 ❯ Object.getElementError node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:37:19
 ❯ getElementError node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:20:35
 ❯ getMultipleElementsFoundError node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:23:10
 ❯ node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:55:13
 ❯ node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:95:19
 ❯ src/components/__tests__/SUList.spec.ts:54:33
     52|
     53|         render(TmpList, { props: { listItems, selectable: true }, slots: { 'item-content': slotTemplate } });
     54|         const firstItem = screen.getByText(listItems[0]);
       |                                 ^
     55|         await fireEvent.click(firstItem);
     56|         expect(firstItem.classList).toContain('selected-item')
```

I know I could use the *getAllByText* method to query multiple items, but in this test I am expecting only one element to be found. The duplication is related to the rendering in the test, not an issue with the actual component.

Am I doing something wrong when writing the tests? Is there a way to ensure that each render will be executend independetly of renders from other tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `render()` returns `@testing-library`'s methods (query* /get* /find* ) ***scoped** to the template being rendered*.

In other words, they normally require a `container` parameter, but when returned by `render`, the `container` is already set to that particular `render`'s DOM:

```js
it('should select on click', async () => {
  const { getByText } = render(TmpList, {
    props: { listItems, selectable: true },
    slots: { 'item-content': slotTemplate },
  })

  const firstItem = getByText(listItems[0])
  expect(firstItem).not.toHaveClass('selected-item')

  await fireEvent.click(firstItem)
  expect(firstItem).toHaveClass('selected-item')
})
```

Notes:

- <strike>`fireEvent` is no longer returning a promise in latest versions of `@testing-library`. If, in the version you're using, still returns a promise, keep the `async`</strike> - only true for `@testing-library/react`.
- you want to get to a point where you no longer need to import `screen` in your test suite

---

If you find yourself writing the same selector or the same render parameters multiple times, it might make sense to write a `renderComponent` helper at the top of your test suite:

```
describe(`<ListItems />`, () => {
  // define TmpList, listItems, slotTemplate
  const defaults = {
    props: { listItems, selectable: true },
    slots: { 'item-content': slotTemplate },
  }
  const renderComponent = (overrides = {}) => {
    // rendered test layout
    const rtl = render(TmpList, {
      ...defaults,
      ...overrides
    })
    return {
      ...rtl,
      getFirstItem: () => rtl.getByText(listItems[0]),
    }
  }

  it('should select on click', async () => {
    const { getFirstItem } = renderComponent()
    expect(getFirstItem()).not.toHaveClass('selected-item')

    await fireEvent.click(getFirstItem())
    expect(getFirstItem()).toHaveClass('selected-item')
  })

  it('does something else with different props', () => {
    const { getFirstItem } = renderComponent({ 
      props: /* override defaults.props */
    })
    // expect(getFirstItem()).toBeOhSoSpecial('sigh...')
  })
})
```

Note I'm spreading `rtl` in the returned value of `renderComponent()`, so all the `get*`/`find*`/`query*` methods are still available, for the one-off usage, not worth writing a getter for.

Comment: Thank you for the help, after playing around with the code and implementing your suggestions everything is now working as I expected.
As a note for others, I am using `@testing-library/vue`, which in its' latest version (6.6.1) still seems to return promises when using `fireEvent`.

Comment: I use it for both Vue and React and I rely on my IDE to tell me where `async` is redundant. I'm pretty sure in the react package they've removed the promise but I have no idea if that's also planned for vue. Updated the answer.